# Pull facebook data xml

Tags: php, html, mysql, xml

```
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/links.getStats/
```

Okay I have looked at the site above. but im still having some trouble.

I have formated what I need like this

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=dogtags.com.com,http://www.petsmart.com

My only issue is I need this data to be picked by the zip code another words I only want to see how many likes are on the url http://www.petsmart.com in the zip code 66614. How can I add that variable to the xml data displaying

Thank you all help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are using an outdated facebook API. I would recommend implementing:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/

However, I do not believe there is any way to to look at data from a specific zip-code using the facebook insight API